# Bosch washer won't start. Some lights are blinking

Tags: repair, washing-machine

I have a Bosch washer model WAS20160UC. After I turn the programming selector to the desired position, the Start/Pause light comes on, then after a moment Spin, Regular Spin, and End lights start flashing and the washer wouldn't do anything. Sears sent a technician to my house - he said the problem is with the door lock. Today, the new lock has arrived and I've installed it, but nothing has changed. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: I'd call Sears again, and ask for a replacement washer (or if it's a new unit a refund).

Comment: The extended warranty on this product just expired. Now I have something called "service agreement" with Sears, where they provide repairs and I pay only if the repair costs more than $500. So, I don't think I could get a new machine out of them.

Comment: Have you tried turning off power at the breaker, waiting several minutes, and then turning the breaker back on?

Comment: +1 on "rebooting" the unit.  Also disassemble and check for water on the circuit boards.